# Data in a MySQL Database is not being updated. Any thoughts?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, sql-update

I am trying to use the below to update a MySQL DB.  I connect fine and get no errors when submitting a change yet the DB is not showing any changes. Any thoughts?

```
    <?php
//replace usernaem,password, and yourdb with the information for your database
mysql_connect("######","######","######") or die("Error: ".mysqlerror());
mysql_select_db("#####");

//get the variables transmitted from the form 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $trailName = $_POST['trailName'];
    $trailDesc = $_POST['trailDesc'];
    $trailHike = $_POST['trailHike'];
    $trailBike = $_POST['trailBike'];

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE markers SET trailName='$trailName', trailDesc='$trailDesc', trailHike='$trailHike' WHERE id='$id'";

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

echo "Database updated. <a href='edit.php'>Return to edit info</a>";
?>
```

Comment: have you confirmed that `$id` has a valid value?

Comment: try running the sql directly without php.

Comment: add mysql_affected_rows() to see how many rows changed

Comment: Please, do run your POST variables through mysql_real_escape_string. And the best way to test your query is to run it using PHPMyAdmin or similar client instead of trying to debug it in PHP. What you can do in PHP is simply print it like echo $sql to see the actual query that's being run.

Comment: Do you get a mysql error? or no error just database doesn't update?

Comment: To expand on AR's post, what if I used a tool like Tamper Data to fiddle with the POST parameters, and set trailName to be `x'; DROP TABLE markers --`? Now you might be thinking that I'm a jerk (which I don't like to think I am), but lots of people on the Internet are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because the where clause in the update statement is not finding the id you are passing it.

Comment: This was it! I needed to change to WHERE ID='$id'  vs id=   I guess it was case sensitive?

Comment: @RonnieT Yes probably, for windows it doesn't matter, but Unix is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in query. your query suppose to  be like this..

UPDATE markers SET trailName='".$trailName."', trailDesc='".$trailDesc."', trailHike='".$trailHike."' WHERE id='$id'

Comment: quoting is the biggest trouble with php/mysql.

Comment: Don't forget to escape all user inputted strings!

Comment: No, it's not. It's just ridiculous BS. There are NO issues with the syntax.

Comment: @balki - quoting is not AT ALL a trouble with PHP. Not the biggest, nor the smallest. There simply isn't any issue with quoting. Any color-coded editor like Notepad ++ will tell you straight away if you didn't use quotes properly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OscarMk: the id is probably not being found. Why are you quoting the id value in the update query? IDs are usually INTs, and should not be quoted.